# How to remove icons in Plotly Dash chart tool bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

Currently I have developed charts using python Plotly Dash library and I want to customize their inbuilt chart toolbar

toolbar image

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use config option in chart parameter. If you want to remove logo use 'displaylogo': False, 
then to remove icons use modeBarButtonsToRemove parameter

```
config={
    'displayModeBar': True,
    'displaylogo': False,                                       
    'modeBarButtonsToRemove': ['zoom2d', 'hoverCompareCartesian', 'hoverClosestCartesian', 'toggleSpikelines']
  },
```

Comment: For anyone else wondering along looking to do this in a dashboard, the `config` dictionary goes in `dcc.Graph(figure=fig, config=config)` if you didn't catch that.